# How many PNG images can I use in an animation sequence?

Tags: android, animation, png

I have like 45 PNG files that I want to use in a animation sequence using the XML animation file. I noticed that I'm not able to animate past 10 PNG files, any more then that I get problems where the animation does play past the 10th image or it would just crash.

Is there a way to get past that limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need check the **crash** reason, **if it the Out of memory error, you can try make the png pictures pixel smaller**.

if it's the system animation size limit, you can try another method, you can create your view and in your view create a `Handler`, and handler send message every time(the animation every duration time), when receive the message, change the png.

**added:**

```
static final int MSG_ANIMATION = 1, MSG_CANCEL = 2;

static final int ANIMATION_DURATION = 500;

public Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        final int what = msg.what;
        if (what == MSG_ANIMATION) {
            // here change the animation png
            setImageResource(..);
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_ANIMATION, ANIMATION_DURATION);
        } else if (what == MSG_CANCEL) {
            removeMessages(MSG_ANIMATION);
        }
    };
};

public void startAnimation() {
    // set first animation png
    setImageResource(..);
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_ANIMATION, ANIMATION_DURATION);
}

public void stopAnimation() {
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_CANCEL);
}
```

Comment: I will give this a try, could you point me in the direction to create a handler or give me an idea what I can use to report this?

Comment: You were absolutely right! It was an out of memory error, it said the "the bitmap size exceeds VM budget." I didn't even think to try it on my phone, which it did work LOL!

Comment: You can also try to optimize the PNG files using something like http://trimage.org which is lossless compression